# How does WCF queue one way operations with netTcp binding

Tags: wcf, sockets, tcp

I have a server that is calling back to the client through a callback channel.

The callback contract operations are all marked as IsOneWay. The binding is netTcp.

I sometimes have the scenario where the server is generating more messages than the client can handle (I can simulate this by putting a sleep into the client method).

Eventually I get a "`CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted`"

Unfortunately I have no idea what is going on under the hood.

- Is the operation queued on the send
  or receive side, or both?
- Can I monitor these queues?
- What causes the timeout?
- Does WCF have threads that constantly write/read to the socket?
- Does WCF on the receive side eventually stop reading from the socket hence the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

To get more info on whats going on , try to turn on WCF tracing , and using the trace viewer to look at the output. [here`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) how to turn on tracing, and use the MS trace view utility [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

in a more direct answer to the question - WCF has a default incomming queue of 10 concurrent sessions, so i'm geussing that this is what you are experiencing when the server stresses the client. it`s possible to configure a larger value though, using the maxConcurrentSessions behaviur parameter.